# Reasons for using transactions in Firebase Database over normal writes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The Firebase documentation states that transactions are used in scenarios where a field might be needed to update frequently(Like a counter,for example.) But I don't get the point, Why cant I just read the data from the database using a listener and write data to the node? I know it's very sketchy but I wanted to know what are the drawbacks of using this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a situation where two clients are both trying to update some count in the database at the same time.  We'll call them Client A and Client B.  Their behavior is ordered like this:

1. Client A reads a count with value 1
2. Client B reads a count with value 1
3. Client A wants to increment the count.  It writes a count of 1+1=2 back to the database.
4. Client B wants to increment the count.  It writes a count of 1+1=2 back to the database.

In this situation, the count *should* be 3, but instead a value a of 2 remains in the database.  The count is obviously wrong now, and a transaction would have prevented the problem by forcing the writes in a particular order, and forcing the second client to re-read the count after the first client updated it.  This means one of the clients updates from 1 to 2, and the second client updates from 2 to 3.  Using a transaction is the only way to ensure correctness in this situation.

Comment: if two users sign up at the same time, thus sending data to the database. Do we need transactions also? or is it only when a specific field is getting updated by two users at the same time?

Comment: It's only needed for the case where it's possible that two clients need to modify the same value.  Writes to different locations by different clients are always OK.