# Firestore, Transaction has already completed

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got 2 Collections, "Users" and "Usernames". I want to save all used usernames with his associated uid seperately , so I can have fast access to them instead of querying thousands of users. It should be used for username selection in the future. To prevent a user to take the same username as someone else, I thought I'll make it in a single Transaction where I first check if the username exists and if not I add it and update the username attribute in "users".
Thats what I have so far:

```
db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void apply(final Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {

            db.collection("usernames").document(editTextUsername.getText().toString()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (!task.getResult().exists()) {
                        transaction.update(sfDocRef, "username", editTextUsername.getText().toString());

                        Map<String, Object> usernameMap = new HashMap<>();
                        usernameMap.put("uid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

                        db.collection("usernames").document(editTextUsername.getText().toString()).set(usernameMap);
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success!");
        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e);
                }
            });
```

If I run my app with this code I get this Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction has already completed.
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeof.zzbb(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeof.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.update(Unknown Source)
 at com.lala.rerere.ProfileAssistant.FragmentUsernameAsk$7$1.onComplete(FragmentUsernameAsk.java:179)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

So I thought the transaction is returning **null** before my query gets into onCompleteListener, probably because it is an asynchronous call. Now I tried to add `getResult()` on the end of my query. Well, it worked ! But I got a ugly warning

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
          at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.zza(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.zzbjk(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.getResult(Unknown Source)
          at com.lala.rerere.ProfileAssistant.FragmentUsernameAsk$7.apply(FragmentUsernameAsk.java:181)
          at com.lala.rerere.ProfileAssistant.FragmentUsernameAsk$7.apply(FragmentUsernameAsk.java:165)
          at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzf.call(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzo.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

What's the best approach in my scenario  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use transactions in this case. We use `transactions` if we know that in our app is a possibility that two users can make the same `write operation` in the same time. We'll use transactions so every write that will be made in the same time by different users, to be made in different thread of execution. That's why we use transactions to avoid inconsistent data.

In your case you only need to use a `get()` call and use `exists()` method and that's it!

Comment: But thats exactly the problem ? What if two users sign up with the same name at the same time ?

Comment: That's no problem, you are only reading data. Firebase does not have a problem with concurent reading, only with writting.

Comment: But when a user wants to add a username it writes a document in the collection "usernames" with his associated uid. Imagine that both users checked if the username exists at the same time and they get the answer that these usernames are free to use. Immediatley another one writes the same document but with his uid. Didnt I lost the first user then ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of transaction. A transaction is used for example when updating a counter. Take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349362/reasons-for-using-transactions-in-firebase-database-over-normal-writes)** for a better understanding. So as an answer to you comment, transaction are used to allow users to make write opperation in the same time not to restrict them, right?

Comment: It's ok now, have you understood it?

Comment: Not really, because I still think It could be get to this point where both user try to write on the same document :S Im sry but thank you for you help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165836/discussion-between-ahmet-kazaman-and-alex-mamo).